# cassandra @table dynamically change name

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data

I have multiple consumers for an API who post similar data into my API. My API needs to consume this data and persist the data into cassandra tables identified by consumer name. Eg. consumername_tablename

My spring boot entity is annotated with @Table which doesn't let me change the table name dynamically. Most recommendations online suggest that its not something we should try and change.

But in my scenario identifying all consumers and creating table in advance doesnt sound right. In future I want to be able to add consumers to my API seamlessly.

I want to use a variable passed in my API call as the prefix for my cassandra table names. Is this something I can achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters: You cannot change annotations without recompiling- they are baked into the compiled class file. This is not the right approach.

Why not put everything in one table and make consumer part of the key? This should give you identical functionality without any of the hassle.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I am contemplating putting everything into one table as it seems to be the only viable approach. But since I am from an Oracle RDBMS background I feel reluctant to pile up everything in one place. But maybe I am being silly in my understanding. But given a genuine usecase, dont you think there should be another way to do something like this?

Comment: I wouldn't do a table per customer in Oracle either. I've done many hundred-million row tables in Oracle with creative use of partitions and Index Organized Tables and gotten great query and insert performance. But that's an aside. In Cassandra, having the customer as part of the partition key is absolutely the right way to go if you will always know which customer you are querying for. If you don't (i.e. you'll ask questions like "show me order ID 638") then having customer as a cluster key field may make more sense.